# rake db:seed is not working using neo4j gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I have stated working on neo4j with rails using the gem 'neo4j', I want to seed some data in neo4j database. But whenever I am trying to do rake db:seed, it says

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:seed'
```

I have checked all the rake tasks using **rake -T**, and there is no **rake db:seed.**

Does any one have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solutions.

Create a file **seed.rake** under **lib/tasks** and put the code

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb'
  task :seed => :environment do
    seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds.rb')
    load(seed_file) if File.exist?(seed_file)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The Neo4j gem doesn't have a seed command. The command you're trying to use is provided by ActiveRecord. We'd love to add this functionality in, though, and if you'd like to help, we'd gladly accept a PR and/or contribute to the process. For now, open up an issue at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues and we can add it to the roadmap.

Comment: Thanks, For the info find a way to do it. Please check my answer. I will fork your git and try to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check apps root directory, is there a Rakefile?
Make a file with name "Rakefile" and enter these line

> "#!/usr/bin/env rake
>   require File.expand_path('../config/application', **FILE**)
>   APP_NAME::Application.load_tasks

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned before, `rails db:seed` is a built-in feature backed by `ActiveRecord`. Assuming you are using neo4jrb without `ActiveRecord`, you won't be able to use this command to seed database any more.

However, you can use [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank) gem to recover this ability.

It does not depend on `ActiveRecord` like `seed_fu` and other seeding gems do. So it will work just fine with neo4jrb.

The process is rather simple.

1. put seedbank in your Gemfile and bundle install.
2. create directory `db/seeds/`
3. create a seeds file under the `db/seeds/` directory

for example

```
#db/seeds/show.seeds.rb

Show.create(name: "Better Call Saul", producer: "Vince Gilligan")
```

4. run rake db:seed:show